# 3d Array Over-writing Values from other dimensions JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong on this code I wrote yesterday. This was my first time whipping up JavaScript, and using jQuery and Node.js also both for the first time, and I would think this three dimensional array should work as is. I've seen confusing mention about what multidimensional arrays are and people saying that JavaScript does not have any, though it has arrays of arrays. Anyways I guess I'm technically using an array of an array of an array, and don't understand why my outer array, which I imagined being an outer dimension by design, over-writes elements from the two inner-arrays into its own elements. The two inner arrays appear to work as they are supposed to, but the outter-most array mixes up the data in some way I don't really understand.

The inconsistency/problem can be observed by scrolling through the output.json file that is generated by this code and seeing that the outputs clearly do not match up with each of the three tables on this webpage I'm scraping from:

```
// My server.js file:
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app         = express();

// the link below is a tutorial I was loosely following
// see http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/scraping-the-web-with-node-js
app.get('/scrape', function(req, res) {

    url = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/4145/kareem-abdul-jabbar'

    request(url, function(error, response, html) {

        if(!error) {

            // utilize the Cheerio library on the returned html, yielding jQuery functionality
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);

            var numOfRows;

            var stats = [[[]]];

            for(var chart = 0; chart < 3; chart++) {

                stats.push([[]]);   // allocates space for each grid on each chart (each set of rows and columns)

                $('.tablehead').eq(chart).filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                    numOfRows = data.children().length - 2;
                    for(var i = 0; i < numOfRows + 1; i++) {
                        stats[chart].push([]); // allocates space for each row in the chart
                    }
                })

                var numOfColumns;

                $('.stathead').eq(chart).filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                    stats[chart][0][0] = data.children().first().text();
                })

                $('.colhead').eq(chart).filter(function(){  // first() specifies to select the first of the three occurances of this class; use eq(param) to find the Nth occurance
                    var data = $(this);
                    numOfColumns = data.children().length; 
                    for(var i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++) {
                        stats[chart][1][i] = data.children().eq(i).text();
                    }
                })

                var currentRow = 2;

                for(var oddRow = 0; oddRow < (numOfRows + 1)/2 - 1; oddRow++) {
                    $('.tablehead .oddrow').eq(oddRow).filter(function(){
                        var data = $(this);
                        for(var c = 0; c < numOfColumns; c++) {
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c] = data.children().eq(c).text();
                        }
                        currentRow += 2;
                    })  
                }   

                currentRow = 3;
                for(var evenRow = 0; evenRow < (numOfRows + 1)/2 - 1; evenRow++){
                    $('.tablehead .evenrow').eq(evenRow).filter(function(){
                        var data = $(this);
                        for(var c = 0; c < numOfColumns; c++) {
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c] = data.children().eq(c).text();
                        }
                        currentRow += 2;
                    })  
                }

                currentRow -= 1; // gets the last allocated row index (after "currentRow += 2" has been executed)
                $('.tablehead .total').eq(chart).filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                    var LOGOIDX = 1;
                    for(var c = 0; c < numOfColumns - 1; c++) {
                        if(c < LOGOIDX) {
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c] = data.children().eq(c).text();
                        }
                        if(c == LOGOIDX) {
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c] = "N.A.";
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c + 1] = data.children().eq(c).text();
                            continue;
                        }
                        else {
                            stats[chart][currentRow][c + 1] = data.children().eq(c).text();
                        }
                    }
                })
            }   // end chart loop
        }

    // Want to parse my json so that it displays in format: "name: value" rather than just "name" as it is now...

        fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(stats, null, 4), function(err){

            console.log('File successfully written! - Check the project directory for the output.json file');
            console.log('Number of columns in chart is: ' + numOfColumns);
        })

        // message to browser reminding that there's no UI involved here.
        res.send('Check the console!')
    })
})

app.listen('8081')

console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: What's the output? What is wrong with the output, what did you expect?

Comment: First guess: You always want `[]` (an empty array), which is then later (in the loop, programmatically) filled with other arrays. `var stats = [[[]]]; // allocates space` sounds like you're in the habit of "declaring" them as multidimensional.

Comment: Hey, sorry, new to SO and didn't see any notifications. I just used pastebin for the first time: http://pastebin.com/TXXEr11F . The output is kind of long so thought it's better online. You can see the data in the first table on the website (http://espn.go.com/nba/player/stats/_/id/4145/kareem-abdul-jabbar) is inside the data in the other two tables when I scraped it, e.g.: I'm overlooking something possibly simple when recording the data in my 3d array.

Comment: But the output looks good, doesn't it? Is it recording the wrong data? Or do you want to get rid of the trailing `[[]]`?

Comment: Hmm, I pushed 3 empty arrays in the outer-most dimension and pushed numOfRows empty arrays in the middle dimension... For a 3d array, are you suggesting I'd also need to push a third set of arrays in in the inner-most dimension? Or would that make it a 4d array? Is there something wrong in the way I'm initializing?

Comment: Lines 515-531 uses the same data as in lines 29-48. And the same goes for lines 934-946, for example. It uses the same set of 1 data chart across all three charts, but just makes things the right length so they may appear correct from an afar glance.

Comment: Yes, the way you're initialising is wrong. It should just be `var stats = [];` - you don't need to put an inner array there for the initialisation, you create and push the subarrays in the loop.

Comment: Hey, I made that one-line change, and this is the diffed result:  `MyComputer:currentDir Me$ diff output.json ../otherDir_revision1/output.json  1247a1248,1250 >     ], >     [ >         [] MyComputer:currentDir Me$`  It helped, but didn't solve the problem of the data being in the wrong dimensions. It just changed a few lines in the file.

^^ originally written 15 mins ago, but deleted to take out some personal information and re-commented back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Caught my bug -- just a simple logical error. Kind of embarrassing I didn't see it earlier, but oh well, got some practice and research (and a fair amount of distraction) by the end of the day:

As it can be seen, all the searching for HTML classes I did were parameterized by a variable named "chart", except for where I searched for odd rows and even rows within each chart -- the actual scraping of the bulk of each chart, so it naively appeared that my "3d array [was] over-writing values from other dimensions" <-- lol.

In simple, I just needed to create an offset based on a condition for each chart (a few extra lines of code), and I needed to edit two lines of code to reflect the newly calculated offset like so:

`$('.tablehead .oddrow').eq(rowOffset + oddRow).filter(function(){`

and

`$('.tablehead .evenrow').eq(rowOffset + evenRow).filter(function(){`

Thanks anyways for any help! I hope this issue tangentially benefits others greatly : P